# Lerna ERR minTimeout is greater than maxTimeout

Tags: jenkins, lerna

I have a problem, when using **lerna** with a **jenkins pipeline**.

This is from the pipeline

```
stage('pre release') {
          when {
            expression { return featureReleaseTypes.contains(params.releaseType) }
          }

          steps {
            script {
              sh """#!/bin/bash -l
                  nvm use
                  npx lerna publish ${params.releaseType} --preid ${job.getJobBranchName()} --yes
                """
            }
          }
        }
```

So basically it's doing `npx lerna publish prerelease --preid xxx --yes`. When i do it locally I don't get this error:

**`lerna ERR! minTimeout is greater than maxTimeout`**

But on jenkins I get this error at the end:

```
lerna notice cli v3.16.4
lerna info ci enabled
lerna info current version 1.3.2-ADR-1439.9
lerna info Looking for changed packages since v1.3.2-ADR-1439.5

Changes:
 - packageNameHere: 1.3.2-ADR-1439.9 => 1.3.2-ADR-1439.10

lerna info auto-confirmed 
lerna info execute Skipping releases
lerna info git Pushing tags...
lerna info publish Publishing packages to npm...
lerna notice Skipping all user and access validation due to third-party registry
lerna notice Make sure you're authenticated properly ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
lerna WARN ENOLICENSE Package packageNameHere is missing a license.
lerna WARN ENOLICENSE One way to fix this is to add a LICENSE.md file to the root of this repository.
lerna WARN ENOLICENSE See https://choosealicense.com for additional guidance.
lerna ERR! minTimeout is greater than maxTimeout
```

Looks like it's related to npm right?

Has someone encountered a similar issue or knows about a possible cause?

lerna 3.16.4
node 10.16.2
npm 6.9.0

### Update

When i downgrade lerna to 3.10.0 I get a more detailed stack trace:

```
lerna ERR! Error: minTimeout is greater than maxTimeout
lerna ERR!     at Object.exports.timeouts (/home/jenkins/workspace/xxx/node_modules/retry/lib/retry.js:28:11)
lerna ERR!     at Object.exports.operation (/home/jenkins/workspace/xxx/node_modules/retry/lib/retry.js:4:26)
lerna ERR!     at promiseRetry (/home/jenkins/workspace/xxx/node_modules/promise-retry/index.js:23:23)
lerna ERR!     at remoteFetch (/home/jenkins/workspace/xxx/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/index.js:329:10)
lerna ERR!     at cachingFetch (/home/jenkins/workspace/xxx/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/index.js:176:10)
```

Comment: i found a solution for my specific setup. I had to create a custom .npmrc and override

fetch-retries, 
fetch-retry-factor,
fetch-retry-maxtimeout,
fetch-retry-mintimeout